# Invalid argument supplied for foreach() $this->supports as $feature => $args

Tags: php, wordpress

I've just updated my Wordpress and I'm having the error message below.

I absolutely don't know anything about PHP, but the error apparently lies on this line :

```
foreach ( $this->supports as $feature => $args ) {
```

Here is the entire code around this line :

```
// Sets the features support for the post type
public function add_supports() {
    if ( ! empty( $this->supports ) ) {
        foreach ( $this->supports as $feature => $args ) {
            if ( is_array( $args ) ) {
                add_post_type_support( $this->name, $feature, $args );
            } else {
                add_post_type_support( $this->name, $args );
            }
        }

        unset( $this->supports );

    } elseif ( false !== $this->supports ) {
        // Add default features.
        add_post_type_support( $this->name, array( 'title', 'editor' ) );
    }
}
```

Could you please help me solve this problem ?

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: What's the exact error message? What have you tried to debug the problem?

Comment: What version of WordPress, and what version of PHP?